# Laravel logical - convert price, so on frontend I have always chf value

Tags: php, database, laravel

This is a little bit heavy. I have in my cms four currencies, usd, gbp, euro and the main one chf. Also, in my cms, admin can add schools, inside of schools you can create courses, and then admin can set the price for the specific course in usd or in gbp, euro or chf. What my assignment is, if school has multiple courses and those courses have all different values, I need to catch the course with lowest price, so I can write on my frontend: "Courses start from XX - CHF".
In my cms, admin can set it's own exchange rate, CHF is always set to 1, but they can add their own values for usd, gbp or euro.

What I have done so far, is take the minimum value for that course and converted it to CHF. And it is working ok.

PROBLEM IS: if one course is set to 10 euro, and another one is set to 10 usd, I will take the first value, so it can calculate 10 euro as a minimal price aldo the 10 usd is the minimum price. So I need somehow, to calculate the currencies inside of query and have no clue how to do that.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public function schoolMinPrice()
{
    $minPrice = DB::table('schools')
            ->select('season_prices.currency', \DB::raw('MIN(season_prices.price) AS min'))
            ->join('courses', function ($query) {
                $query->on('courses.school_id', '=', 'schools.id');
                $query->where('schools.id', '=', $this->id);
            })
            ->join('seasons', 'seasons.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
            ->join('season_prices', 'season_prices.season_id', '=', 'seasons.id')
            ->first();


    $exchangeRate = DB::table('exchange_rates')
            ->select('dollar', 'euro', 'gbp')->get();

    foreach ($exchangeRate as $rate) {
        if ($minPrice->currency == 'chf'){
            return round($minPrice->min);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'usd') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->dollar;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'eur') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->euro;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'gbp') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->gbp;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in my first query I am getting the lowest price in the database:

```
{#732 ▼
+"currency": "usd"
+"min": "5.00"
}
```

And in second query I am getting the currencies from the database set by admin:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#844 ▼
    +"dollar": "1.0000"
    +"euro": "2.0000"
    +"gbp": "3.0000"
  }
]
```

And then I am doing the calculation to convert usd, gbp, euro to chf

```
    foreach ($exchangeRate as $rate) {
        if ($minPrice->currency == 'chf'){
            return round($minPrice->min);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'usd') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->dollar;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'eur') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->euro;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        } else if ($minPrice->currency == 'gbp') {
            $calculated_rate  = 1 / $rate->gbp;
            return round($minPrice->min * $calculated_rate);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, I think all you have to do is add a join to the `$minPrice` query to the `exchange_rates` table using the currency field. Then take the minimum of price * exchange_rate.

Comment: So, I should add in season.prices column exchange_rate_id? I am not sure I understand how exactly can I make those two tables work together?

Comment: I was thinking `->join('exchange_rates AS er', 'season_prices.currency', '=', 'er.???')`. Then `MIN(season_prices.price * ???)`, where the ??? are field names. Are you able to post the structure of those two tables? And maybe a few rows from each?

Comment: In my exchange_rate table I have coulmns: id, dollar, euro, gbp and in season_prices: id, season_id, price, currency and duration_type. I know that somehow I need to change the structure of the exchange rate table, but I really don't know how to relate those two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this problem:

1) Generalize your currency exchange table so that all the rates are relative to CHF. So maybe `exchange_rates` table can have the following columns: `id, currency_name, currency_code, rate`. An example entry would be:
`1, 'US Dollar', 'USD', 0.99`.

2) Modify `season_prices.currency` to be an integer foreign key pointing to `currency_exchange.id`

3) Modify your existing query to link the currency exchange table in and calculate the rate dynamically and select the minimum:

```
$minPrice = DB::table('schools')
                ->join('courses', function ($query) {
                    $query->on('courses.school_id', '=', 'schools.id');
                    $query->where('schools.id', '=', $this->id);
                  })
                ->join('seasons', 'seasons.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
                ->join('season_prices', 'season_prices.season_id', '=', 'seasons.id')
                ->join('exchange_rates', 'season_prices.currency', '=', 'exchange_rates.id')
                ->select('season_prices.currency', \DB::raw('MIN(season_prices.price * exchange_rate.rate) AS min'))
                ->first();
```

Comment: That is the solution!

Comment: @RadomirAntic Glad it helped :) if you could please mark this as the solution